# Protobuf - java package name and sharing proto file across projects

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I have two java projects that produce and consume messages from Kafka,
one project produces a message of type `Ticker` and another project consumes this message.

So I've created this file

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Ticker {
    string symbol = 1;
    float ask = 2;
    float bid = 3;
}
```

I know that in order to create Java objects for this message type, I use `protoc`

However, I have two problems.

1. I need a way of sharing the `proto` file across the project (the 2 projects that I have right now and any future project that would need access to `Ticker`). What is the best way to do it? I've heard something about git subtrees or submodules, is it a good/reliable way?
2. I need a way for `protoc` to generate the Java objects under some package, for a example, I have two projects, one is `com.myorg.TickerProducer` and another one is `com.myorg.TickerConsumer` I need `protoc` to generate the Java objects in the packages/namespaces `com.myorg.TickerProducer.Entities` and `com.myorg.TickerConsumer.Entities` respectively. I know that I can use `option java_package` inside the `proto` file, but I have different projects that use the same files and each want the Java objects to be generated under their namespaces. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single .proto file will always generate code in the same package/namespace, so if you want to have two different layouts in the two projects, you'll need two .proto files. Frankly, though, I'd argue that it is *correct* to have it in the same package/namespace in both: it still *is the same thing*, ultimately.

Note that as long as you aren't using the "any" feature, protobuf doesn't care much about the type-name / package / namespace at runtime; so an `X.Y.Z` will be interchangeable with an `A.B.C` as long as they are actually the same fundamental *shape*. Even field-names are irrelevant as long as you aren't using json.

Comment: So you're suggesting to have the same namespace com.myorg.Entities for all Java projects? what about projects that aren't written in Java? C# for instance, I would have to have both `java_package` and `csharp_namespace` in the same `proto` file, I guess it would work but it makes me feel as though Protobuf was never designed to be shared across different project (let alone projects that are written in different lan gauges). Maybe my whole approach is wrong and I should just maintain a separate `proto` file for each project?

Comment: @areller I'm only talking about these specific entities, not everything - but: yes; and possibly in a library project that *just* contains these shared types - then consume *that library* from both.  As for between languages: that's not a problem at all and works just fine. It is *expected* that you would have a `java_package` and a `csharp_namespace` in the same .proto (in the case where you are using java and c#, obviously).

Comment: It makes sense. It bothers me a bit because I'd expect the `proto` file to be language agnostic since the `protoc` already generates language specific files so it might as well accept a namespace/package. Thank you, very helpful answer. How about storing the `proto` files? Do you suggest to have them in a git repository and use submodules?

Comment: @areller I don't entirely disagree - in fact, for the "old" version of protobuf-net's code-gen tooling, it used to allow the namespace to be specified on the command-line. I haven't retained that for the "new" version of protobuf-net's code-gen tooling, largely to provide consistency with protoc (protobuf-net is just a separate implementation - not based on Google's codebase)

Answer (score 3):

The sanest way to deal with this might be to have a separate package for these entities, which both the consumer and producer use. As long as you don't want the consumer to depend on the producer or vice-versa.

If you're using Gradle, there's a [protobuf-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) which integrates the building of the protobufs into the consumer project's code.

---

In general, there is a slight impedance mismatch between how protobuf's are meant to be used, due to the fact that Google has a single repository where every build unit / package can technically depend on every other build unit / package, and how they are used in the rest of the world, where projects have many repositories, and those act as a hard boundary for visibility and dependence between build units and packages.

If you can add them up to a package containing other common definitions etc. that would be best, but lacking that, a separate package, ugly as it is, might be your safest bet.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at the plugin.

Comment: And where would i store this common package? each project has it's own git repository? should i have a separate git repository for the common `proto` files? how would i access them from my projects?

Comment: @areller that's up to how you structure your project really. If you have a single repository, putting it in a common/ directory might be enough. If you have multiple, then putting it in it's own repository makes the most sense. I usually split it into packages, each one having it's own repository. It seems to be _the way_ most of the tooling works nowadays at least. It's a bit more complex infrastructure-wise for smaller projects, but it's a boon for larger ones, since you have a very clear boundary between projects.